# Private Chrome extensions for business intranet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to build a private Chrome extension that will be used within my client's organization only. What changes would be made to the normal development process that will allow my Chrome extension to be easily install-able, and validated against Chrome technical standards?

Background: My client's business involves using a web app for data entry in the field, often in remote locations with no connectivity. We run our site from localhost for data entry. The Chrome extension I'd like to write will automatically synchronize the local DB updates with the main company DB. It will also check for updates of the web app, download the new version and save it for offline use. Obviously, this Chrome extension will be of no use to a general user so we don't want to submit it to the Chrome store.

Your comments and suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google recently changed their policies regarding [Adding extensions from other websites](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning) outside of the Chrome Web Store. Basically they are removing the ability for users to install self-hosted extensions with one click. They cite security concerns as the reason for the change.

Users can still download the .crx file and drag it onto their Extensions page, but that's certainly not as nice an experience as before.

Note that there is also an option for 'Enterprise Administrators' to use [local policy](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources) to enable installation from certain URLs.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Google Apps, it appears there's now a way to publish apps and extensions to the Chrome Web Store, but only make it visible to users of that domain.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

If you went that route, you wouldn't have to make any changes to your development methodologies, just change a setting when you publish the app.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to [package your own crx files](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html) for deployment and you can even make sure they [autoupdate](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html) just like the Web Store.